# system-images has huge space

Tags: android, android-studio

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\system-images` folder uses **73GB**, which is super huge.

Are there something wrong? Any recommendation? All I need is to open up some spaces; but why it has been listed in the system-images folder.

[image]

In the system-images folder, the following folders are listed.

[image]

When I open Android SDK Manager, I do not see that any API 15,19,20,21,22, and 24 are being installed also.

[image]

Comment: Are you using android emulator?

Comment: I am using android emulator.

Comment: Open Android SDK manager from Android Studio, and check if there any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SDK Manager (Tools -> SDK Manager), uninstall (untick) any SDKs you no longer wish to target / use.

Comment: In that case, delete the unused APIs. They can always be reinstalled easily!

Comment: shall I directly delete through folder system since it is not being listed on android device manager?

Comment: Yep, you can always reinstall if necessary.